# O que é o conceito de inteiros assinados em uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, tipagem, int

Gostaria de esclarecer o significado do termo "inteiro assinado".

Estou  pesquisando sobre protocolos,  para construir um em Java, e vez por outra encontro o termo. Não sei do que se trata.

Sempre ouvi falar em tipos primitivos , por exemplo em Java: `int`, `float`, `double`, ...

Mas pra mim o termo é novo!

Por que se diz que Java "não tem" os tais **inteiros não assinados**?

E qual a diferença entre um "inteiro assinado " e  um "inteiro não assinado"?

Comment: Acredito que java tenha sim os inteiros assinados, o que não tem são os inteiros não assinados.

Comment: Precisa que melhore algo? Acha que pode aceitar agora?

Answer (score 12):

Se por inteiro assinado está querendo dizer inteiro assinalado, é o tipo normalmente usado no Java. O número possui um bit para indicar se ele é positivo ou negativo.

Muitas linguagens possuem tipos sem sinal onde este bit não é considerado, por isso só guarda números positivos, mas pode ir até o dobro do mesmo tipo com sinal. Java não é uma dessas linguagens. Eles consideraram que isso é uma simplificação na linguagem.

Até faz algum sentido porque é comum as pessoas usarem ele errado e em poucas situações eles são necessários em aplicações de alto nível. Porém onde é preciso não pode usar, se precisar interoperar com código externo terá dificuldades.

Em C#, por exemplo existe o `ushort` (vai até 65535), `uint` (até 4294836225) `ulong` (até 18445618199572250625), sendo que o `byte` (até 255) já é não sinalizado, e o `sbyte` é que usa um sinal.

Então o sinal descrito aí é o `+` ou `-`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).